# Css style stops working on partial postback

Tags: asp.net, html, css, styles, updatepanel

in a ASP.net C# application

I have a Checkbox with a custom css.

the Css file is:

```
<link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

the check box

```
<input id="boxcheck" runat="server" type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="customCheckbox" onclick="ChangeSett();"/>
```

Everything works correctly.

But when I put it inside an update panel. The style is lost when I do a partial postback.

Thanks for any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [User controls inside an UpdatePanel - css styles are gone when updating (IE8)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842368/user-controls-inside-an-updatepanel-css-styles-are-gone-when-updating-ie8)

Comment: I tried that. it did not work

Comment: @Youssef Are you using master page? Try my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problem.
 **I solved it moving css `<link ..` from the `<page>` to the `<header>`.**

Since I use a MasterPage and I don't want the link in all pages, I found useful putting a ContentPlaceHolder in the MasterPage's Header

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
  ...
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeaderContentPlaceHolder" runat="server"/>
</head>
```

and then the link inside the desired page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderContentPlaceHolder"       Runat="Server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/my.css" />
</asp:Content>
```