# UpdatePanel doesn't allow code to be executed

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, dotnetnuke

I am working on a project in asp.net and I added a FileUpload, that is going to add the file into a specific folder in my project.

But the problem is that if I put the Button that will execute the code by click, into the UpdatePanel, it doesn't save the file into the folder!! It also doesn't show any errors, it just dosn't execute the code:(

How can I execute the code, even if the button is inside the UpdatePanel?

Comment: Can we have that code?

Comment: Is FileUpload inside the UpdatePanel?

Comment: ` string fileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\websites\dnndev.me\DesktopModules\UshtrimiDyte\images\", FileUpload1.FileName);`

`FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileName);` Here isthe code

Comment: It doens't matterif th Fileupload is inside r outside the UpdatePanel, I tried to putin it outside but still had the problem.... the only thing that doesn't allow the code to executed is if I put the button into the updatepanel

Comment: Did you set a trigger for the Updatepanel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ive had this problem in the past , it's due to the fact that the FileUpload control does not work with asynchronous postbacks, and therefore does not work from within an AJAX UpdatePanel. 
I found this aticle on the codeproject very helpful :
[CodeProject-UpdatePanel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16945/Simple-AJAX-File-Upload)

Comment: thnx @Alicia, it worked but there is only one problem... when i click the button it refreshes th page, and changes the font style :(... why that? Can you help me ?

Comment: Hi user2478115 , glad to help . Do you have your css in a seperate file or inline on the page ? Perhaps this answer here will help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842368/user-controls-inside-an-updatepanel-css-styles-are-gone-when-updating-ie8